# How to change background view color partialy in ios swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

New to swift i want my background view 80% height to be red and rest in blue. Currently i'm doing that adding two views. I think there is a direct way to do that. Any guidance or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for help. I think i found a solution.Adding a sublayer does the trick.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
let bottomBorder = CALayer()
let t = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: (self.view.frame.size.height/100.0)*80, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: (self.view.frame.size.height/100.0)*20)
bottomBorder.frame = t
bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
self.view.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding two views is a good way of getting what you want (and the best since you can set the % via constraints.)

An other way would be by adding sublayers to your view via the code:

```
let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
let topColor = UIColor(red:223.0/255.0, green:142.0/255.0, blue:219.0/255.0, alpha:255.0/255.0).cgColor
let bottomColor = UIColor(red:0, green:201.0/255.0, blue:243.0/255.0, alpha:255.0*0.34).cgColor
gradient.colors = [topColor, UIColor.clear, bottomColor]
gradient.locations = [0.0 , 0.5, 1.0]
gradient.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 1)
```

I would only use the layer method if you want to do something funky like a gradient.

Comment: you can also use 2 sublayers instead of 2 subviews: is faster use less resources.

Comment: The other issue with using two views is if you care to add subviews to one or both of those views.

Comment: issue i'm facing using two views is checking zposition always for other addon views.